# coordinate system in AF manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

we know that an end of $(M,g)$ is asymptotically flat if it is diffeomorphic to the complement of a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the metric tensor $g$ satisfies $$|g_{ij}-\delta_{ij}|\leq\frac{C}{|x|},|g_{ij,k}|\leq\frac{C}{|x|^2}, Ric\geq-\frac{Cg}{|x|^2}, as |x|\rightarrow\infty$$
where the derivatives is respect to the Euclidean metric $\delta$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash K$. 
I am unclear about the coordinate system in this definition. Is the coordinate frame global? 
where is the original point?

Comment: The coordinates in the inequalities are the ones implied by the diffeomorphism.

Comment: @DeaneYang In some papers they construct coordinate at infinity. what does that mean?

Comment: @DeaneYang If we choose $K=B_1(0)$, where is the point such as $p=(\frac 12,\frac 12,\frac 12)$ in $(M,g)$.

Comment: The diffeomorphism in the definition are the co-ordinates at infinity. I don't understand your second question. In any case, these are not research level questions. You should try math.stackexchange.com instead. Or, if you are a student somewhere, you could ask a professor or classmate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right and I am clear now.